# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in React 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm trying to show lists of objects such as types and brands that I have in DyeStore my react app and after using map my app crashes but vs code doesn't tell about errors.

The following error occurs in these components:

```
const BrandBar = observer(() => {
    const {dye} = useContext(Context)
    return (
        <Form className='d-flex'>
            {dye.Brands.map(brand=>
                <Card key={brand.id} className="mt-2" onClick={()=> dye.SetSelectedBrand(brand)} border={brand.id === dye.SetSelectedBrand.Id ? 'danger' : 'light'} style={{cursor:'poiinter'}}>
                    {brand.name}
                </Card>
                )}
        </Form>
      );
  }
)
```

```
const TypeBar = observer(() => {
    const {dye} = useContext(Context)
    return (
        <ListGroup>
            {dye.Types.map( type =>
                <ListGroup.Item 
                    style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
                    active = {type.id === dye.SetSelectedType.id }
                    onClick={() => dye.SetSelectedType(type)}
                    key={type.id}>

                </ListGroup.Item>)}
        </ListGroup>
      );
  }
)
```

This is the class where I store my brands and types arrays.

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"

export default class DyeStore{
    constructor(){
        this._Types = [
            {id:1,name:'Акриловая'}
        ]
        this._Brands = [
            {id:1,name:'Самсунг'}
        ]
        this._Dyes = [
            {id:1,name:'Самсунг',price: 2400,rating:5}
        ]
        this._SelectedType = {}
        this._SelectedBrand = {}
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }
}
```

I also have setters and getters for DyeStore:

What errors I got:

[image: What errors I got]

I was trying to resolve this problem myself but most of the answers were not in the theme so.

Comment: did you try logging `dye` value and see how it changes ?

Comment: It looks like your variable names are wrong e.g. in the constructor you name it `_Brands` (with an underscore) whereas in your `BrandBar` component, you're calling `Brands`.